# on_command_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exc'

Tags: python, sqlite, discord

code:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, exc):
    if  isinstance(exc, CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f"Подождите, команда будет доступна через {exc.retry_after} секунд")
```

cmd:
Bot connected
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\gnati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_command_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exc'
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\gnati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the positional argument, but the type placed in the isinstance (that is "CommandOnCooldown") should be like this Instead:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(self,ctx,error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f"Подождите, команда будет доступна через {exc.retry_after} секунд")
```

Give an Upvote if it works :)

Comment: Bot connected
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gnati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_command_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'error'

Comment: Show the Code Please, and I would prefer to say :
```else:
    raise error
```To proceed other errors

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7rZkkeaaU8&t=433s&ab_channel=CarberraTutorials

Answer (score 0):

it's exacpting 3 positional arguments but you have given it 2

should be like this Instead:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx,error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f"Подождите, команда будет доступна через {error.retry_after} секунд")
```

and please check the docs

**Event Reference**

- [on_command_error](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.on_command_error)